# Regular expression in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I have to parse this format using regexp in TCL. 
Here is the format

```
              wl -i eth1 country

              Q1 (Q1/27) Q1
```

I'm trying to use the word country as a keyword to parse the format 'Q1 (Q1/27) Q1'.
I can do it if it is in a same line as country using the following regexp command.

```
   regexp {([^country]*)country(.*)} $line match test country_value
```

But how can i tackle the above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the regular expression you are using isn't doing quite the right thing in the first place, because `[^country]` matches a *set* of characters that consists of everything except the letters in `country` (so it matches from the `h` in `eth1` onwards only, given the need to have `country` afterwards).

By default, Tcl uses the whole string to match against and newlines are just ordinary characters. (There is an option to make them special by also specifying `-line`, but it's not on by default.) This means that if I use your whole string and feed it through `regexp` with your regular expression, it works (well, you probably want to `string trim $country_value` at some point). This means that your *real* problem is in presenting the right string to match against.

If you're presenting lines one at a time (read from a file, perhaps) and you want to use a match against one line to trigger processing in the next, you need some processing outside the regular expression match:

```
set found_country 0
while {[gets $channel line] >= 0} {
    if {$found_country} {
        # Process the data...
        puts "post-country data is $line"
        # Reset the flag
        set found_country 0
    } elseif {[regexp {(.*) country$} $line -> leading_bits]} {
        # Process some leading data...
        puts "pre-country data is $leading_bits"
        # Set the flag to handle the next line specially
        set found_country 1
    }
}
```

If you want to skip blank lines completely, put a `if {$line eq ""} continue` before the `if {$found_country} ...`.

Comment: That last bit, with `continue` is because I can't quite be sure if that blank line is there in your input data or not. It's easily handled though.